# Imputing floots into Watirs text field

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to imput data from an array into a web site, however i am getting an error. I beleive the error means that I can't put floots into text fields, so i I changed the floot into a string. But again it did not work. I have only included the part of the code that I felt was relevant.

Blockquote

```
eee = Watir::Browser.new 

    eee.goto(fulllink)
    eee.text_field(:name => "txtAttr").set Headings[j]
    eee.wait
    p = j + 1 
    strings = body.at(0).at(p)
    String (strings)
    eee.text_field(:name => "txtValue").set strings
    eee.wait
    eee.link(:index => 4).click 
    eee.wait
    eee.close
    end 
    i += 1 


C:\Users\Pure.itloaner1-12\Google Drive\ruby>ruby ExST.rb
hello world
Alpha Numeric Unit #
tables filled
200.0
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/input_
elements.rb:356:in `characters_in': undefined method `each_char' for 200.0:Float
 (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/input_elements.rb:337:in `type_by_character'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-c
lassic/input_elements.rb:299:in `set'
        from ExST.rb:92:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could we possibly mean "input floats?" I'm not sure what a *floot* is, but I'd sure hate to *impute* anything about one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try if changing `String(strings)` to `strings = String(strings)` works.